# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=\sum^n_{k=1} x^k/(x^k+1)$

Tags: real-analysis

The question is :

Find the range of uniform convergence of
$$f_n(x)=\sum^n_{k=1} \dfrac{x^k}{x^k+1}$$
which converges pointwise in $(-1,1)$.

Since at $x=+1$ and $x=-1$ the function diverges, I think Weierstrass M-test for $[-1+\epsilon,1-\epsilon]$ will be useful(Maybe this range for any $\epsilon>0$ will be the answer..), but finding $M_k$ is not so easy for me.

Can I get some hint for this?

Comment: Hint: Bound $f_n(x)$ by a geometric series.

Comment: @JackyChong When $x\geq 0$ it works by using $x^k+1\geq 1$ but I can't manage the negative side. Could you help me a little bit more?

Comment: for $|x| \le r < 1$, you can use that $|\frac{x^k}{x^k+1}| \le \frac{|x|^k}{1-r^k} \le \frac{|x|^k}{1-r}$  so it converges uniformly as the geometric series. at $x = 1$, it diverges since  $\frac{x^k}{x^k+1}= 1/2$, and something worse happens on any $x= e^{2i \pi a/n} \ne 1$ (a dense subset of $|x|= 1$) where $x^k+1$ vanishes for some $k$, hence the domain of uniform convergence is $|x| \le r$ for any $r < 1$

Comment: @user1952009 Very thanks, cleared!